# Open a base64 pdf on chrome IOS tab

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, pdf

I'm generating a base64 pdf , I just need to show it in another iOS chrome tab. I have the following code for it.

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.includes('CriOS')) {
  var base64PDF = base64ArrayBuffer(response.data);
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write('<iframe id="myIframe" width="600" height="315" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64PDF + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>');
  win.document.write('<script>window.open(window.document.getElementById("myIframe").src) </script>');

} else if (navigator.userAgent.includes('iPad') || navigator.userAgent.includes('iPhone')) {
  var base64PDF = base64ArrayBuffer(response.data);
  window.location.assign('data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64PDF);
}
```

that code let me show the pdf on an iframe, but when I do that , the window.location.href is the url that generates the pdf, and the url in the tab is about:blank.

So I decided to write a script in the document that executes window.open with the src of the iframe but I get an empty page in another tab.

I'm looking for set in the url of the chrome tab the data:application/pdf;base64,..... that will show to the user the option "Open In" and he will have the options like , send by gmail or mail, etc. Actually I can't do that because the url is about:blank and not a valid PDF base64 link.

I already try somethings like 
window.location, window.open, window.location.href, window.location.assign, programmatically create an a tag and click it for change the href, and nothing more happens that open a about:blank tab.

When i try , something like window.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,.....;return false;' , google chrome redirect to a new tab with the url correct, but with the return false; sentence in the last part or the url so that do a wrong pdf.

i dont know why programmatically you cant open that data:application..... but if you create a iframe like i mention at first of this post, and you drag the iframe with your finger pressed to another tab , chrome open the data:application...... in the url of the tab.

Comment: You need  `win.document.close()` after the last write for one

Comment: I already try it but window.open(url, '_blank') always ignore the url (base64PDF) or another url, it only happens in IOS , iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Likely a security issue

Answer (score 0):

```
var divpdf = document.createElement('div');
divpdf.innerHTML = '<object  style="display:none;" id="docuFrame" type="application/pdf" width="1px" height="1px" data="' +
linkSource + '"></object>';
document.lastElementChild.appendChild(divpdf);
var frame = document.getElementById('docuFrame') as HTMLObjectElement;
window.open(frame.data);
frame.remove();
divpdf.remove();
```